# Backbone's preferred way of triggering navigate on link clicks?

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a preferred way to trigger `Router.navigate` in Backbone when a user clicks a link?

For instance a template might have a link `<a href="/logout">Log Out</a>`.  Is the preferred approach really to use a custom class and attach a click handler to that class in the view?  This seems to generate tons of duplicate code so I'm looking for a better way.

Answer (score 3):

The way to handle this kind of thing is to extend the Backbone objects ( in this case the View).  You'll notice in the Backbone docs that this is encouraged, and necessary given its minimalist code base.  I'd recommend checking out [Marionette](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette) (on Github) and the site [Backbone patterns](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/) for good ways to extend the Backbone core.

For example, maybe you extend *View* with a method that wires up the navigation handlers as you like:

```
Backbone.View.prototype.wireupNavs = function() {
    var that = this;
    this.$el.find("a[role=nav]").each(function() {
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        that.bind("click", router.navigate(target);
    });
}
```

Then any *a* tag you want as a Backbone nav element, you'd just decorate with the *role="nav"* attribute; and call *this.wireupNavs()* in the *initializer* function of the appropriate views.

Comment: btw, `this.$el.find(...)` is equivalent to `this.$(...)`. so it's possible to write just like: `this.$("a[role=nav]").each(function() {...`